# Is it possible to create a custom X axis in the chart?

Tags: c#, winforms, mschart

I wonder if it is possible to implement such a schedule.

It is necessary to make a graph with a non-standard axis X, which has such intervals:

0: 0.208 - 0.208: 0.701 - 0.701: 1.195

The figure is more clear.

So far the next ones are ready.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double[] ipp = { 0.255, 0.232, 0.618, 0.713 };
    double[] pgc = { 0.154, 0.091, 0.176, 0.185 };

    Series s1 = chart1.Series.Add("buble-chart");

    s1.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Bubble;
    s1.MarkerStyle = MarkerStyle.Circle;
    s1.BorderWidth = 1;
    s1.BorderColor = Color.Black;

    chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = 1.195;
    chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Interval = Math.Round(1.195 / 3, 3);
    chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Maximum = 0.25;
    chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Interval = 0.25 / 4;

    chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.RoundAxisValues();
    chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.RoundAxisValues();

    s1["BubbleScaleMin"] = "0";

    for (int i = 0; i < ipp.Length; i++)
    {
        s1.Points.AddXY(ipp[i], pgc[i], ipp[i]);
    }
}
```

Please tell me, is it possible to realize this at all?

[image]

Comment: You can control the grid interval and offset.

Comment: `Axis ax = chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX;
ax.MajorGrid.Interval = 0.5;
ax.MajorGrid.IntervalOffset = 0.2;
ax.Interval = 0.5;
ax.IntervalOffset = 0.2;`

Comment: thank you very much, it turned out exactly what I needed